# Django user password hash, oracle db, and java

Tags: java, python-3.x, django, oracle

im developing and ecommerce site on django for a Sushi Restaurant, and i have to create a CRUD for users in java and edit info from the database in oracle, the database are generated with django, so my questions are.

how can i deal with the django hash for password? change password from the java crud app would be nice, if can i disable the hash from django would be nice to, its just a institute project, so doesn't matter the security.

Comment: "its just a institute project, so doesn't matter the security." Please don't; implement the security properly now and learn good practices rather than bad habits. What is wrong with Django's password hash? Why would it prevent you from changing the password in Java? Can you not just ask for a new password then hash (and salt) it and store the hash (and salt) in your Django app replacing the old hash?

Comment: why cant you setup an REST API on Django and connect the java program to the API ?

Comment: im out of time so i cant implement something that i have to learn practically from scratch, i just want to know how to disable django hash.